# Html Video player out of screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive html video player for my site. It's a vertical video player with 9:16 ratio. When it loads the full video is not visible without scroll (some part is out of screen and needs to be scrolled) . I want it to be fully visible without scrolling. Help me with CSS to fix this issue.

HTML :

```
<div class="vidcont">
<video preload="none" controls="true" controlsList="nodownload">
<source src="https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-girl-in-neon-sign-1232-large.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
```

CSS :

```
.vidcont video {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code

Comment: Provide a minimal code of what you have for proper clarity.

Comment: try this one https://codepen.io/sunny-parsana/pen/RwgjmWY

Comment: just add `body { margin:0;}`  in `<style>` tag

Comment: @RDX added code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>videobg</title>
    <style>
    body {
      margin:0;
    }
    .mainblock{width:100%; float:left; margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:100vh; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.mainblock #video-background{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:100%; 
}
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .mainblock #video-background{width:auto; height:100vh;}
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainblock">
        <video preload="metadata" id="video-background" controls="" autoplay="" loop="" playsinline="" muted="">
          <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not working. it's cropping the video.

Comment: @AatishKumar try it outside the codepen

Comment: i tried it live. not on codepen.